# Filter data relation on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have data on variable here :

```
const data = {FID: 11
              Kode_Provi: 31
              Provinsi: "DKI Jakarta"
             },
             {
              FID: 20
              Kode_Provi: 35
              Provinsi: "Surabaya"
              }
```

and I try to filter data when I set message FID. Wanted result property is `Provinsi`.

Example, When I set message FID=20 the result is Surabaya.

This is what I am doing now:

```
if (message.includes(data[0].FID)) {
    respon.text = data[0].Provinsi
} else if (message.includes(data[1].FID)) {
    respon.text = data[1].Provinsi
}
```

I would like to find an optimized way of doing this because there is a lot of data.
Any suggestion to doing this?

```
if (message.includes(ask)) {
    respon.text = answer
}
```

Comment: What structure is data? is it an object or an array?

Comment: @V.Sambor i think is object

Comment: show the entire code of that part please, I will figure it out.

Comment: And also what is `message` is it a string, an array or what?

Comment: @V.Sambor message is string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data that you posted isn't in a valid format. I'm guessing that you want an array, in which case your data should be structured like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    FID: 11,
    Kode_Provi: 31,
    Provinsi: "DKI Jakarta"
  },
  {
    FID: 20,
    Kode_Provi: 35,
    Provinsi: "Surabaya"
  }
]
```

Now, with the data in this format, we can take a look at the [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

Using this `filter` function, you can write your own function do what you want:

```
/**
 * This function will return null if the message can't be found in the
 * data array or if either inputs are invalid.
 */
function getProvinsiForMessage(data, message) {
  if (data && message) {
    const result = data.filter(dataEntry => message.includes(dataEntry.FID));

    return result && result.length ? result[0].Provinsi : null;
  }

  return null;
}
```

and now you can do what you want:

```
respon.text = getProvinsiForMessage(data, message);
```

Comment: sorry iam beginer, what does getItemById mean? i have error with that.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake with my naming, but I corrected it. Let me know if it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below syntax. You can study the arrow operator to understand this better.

```
respon.text = data.filter(d => message.includes(d.FID))[0].Provinsi;
```

Please note you need to handle the condition when the value is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Your data does not have a valid format, you could for example use an array instead, like so:

```js
const data = [
  { FID: 11, Kode_Provi: 31, Provinsi: "DKI Jakarta" },
  {
    FID: 20,
    Kode_Provi: 35,
    Provinsi: "Surabaya"
  }
];
```

and then filter and map in order to get all the "Provinsi"s:

```js
let fid = 20;
data.filter(obj => obj.FID === fid).map(result => result.Provinsi); // ['Surabaya']
```